# Why does this CREATE TABLE statement fail?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is wrong with this SQL query-

```
CREATE TABLE emp_dept_join2
(
 employee_id Number,
 department_id Number,
 first_name Varchar2);
```

I am getting

> ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis error.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually the VARCHAR2 that requires a size

```
  CREATE TABLE emp_dept_join2
  (
     employee_id Number,
     department_id Number,
     first_name Varchar2(10)
  )
 ;

Table created.
```